# Code::Blocks - std::bad_alloc

Tags: mysql, c++, codeblocks, mint

Após eu executar este simples código.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <jdbc/cppconn/connection.h>
#include <jdbc/cppconn/driver.h>

int main()
{
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Driver *driver;

    std::cout << "connecting to mysql server..." << std::endl;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "");
    std::cout << "connecting to mysql server with sucessfully...." << std::endl;
    std::cout << con->isClosed() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ate aqui o programa executa normalmente.." << std::endl;
    con->setSchema("secao05"); // Dispara o erro nesta linha
    std::cout << "Apos o erro nada e executado!" << std::endl;

    delete con;

    return 0;
}
```

da erro na linha 18:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O banco de dados no qual eu estou tentando conectar também e bem pequeno tem apenas 10 INSERT.

EDIT:

Quando eu mudo a versão do compilador de c++17 para c++11 o erro muda para:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
>   what():  Unknown database 't' Aborted (core dumped)
>
> Process returned 134 (0x86)   execution time : 0.299 s Press ENTER to
>   continue.

Comment: Verifique as versões de seu server e do jdbc. Pesquise se a incompatibilidade foi corrigida nas versões em uso.

Comment: Server version: 8.0.17, e a versão do connector é Connector/C++ 8.0.17, ambas são as versões mais atualizadas no site oficial do mySQL